# Проверить строки через регулярное выражение

Tags: php, строки

Подскажите как правильно составить регулярное выражение?

Под проверку могут попасть строки такого вида, но нужно пропустить только строки где есть только цифры (строка может содержать теги а может и приходить уже без них)

```
<p><sub>54545454</sub> <em>паапвапвапвап</em></p> - false
54545454 паапвапвапвап - false
<p><sub>54545454</sub></p> -true
54545454 - true
```

Comment: а пробелы в счёт? например `324 23    242 342   2342` - это true или false?

Comment: Нет пробелы тоже false

Comment: `strip_tags` + `ctype_digit`

Answer (score 1):

Базовый вариант без каких-либо регулярных выражений:

```
$tests = [
    '<p><sub>54545454</sub> <em>паапвапвапвап</em></p>',
    '54545454 паапвапвапвап',
    '<p><sub>54545454</sub></p>',
    '54545454',
];
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_dump(ctype_digit(strip_tags($test)));
}

// Вывод
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на вооружение. Но к сожалению требование чтобы была регулярка.

Сейчас пишу так но он находит не то что нужно (где-то ошибка)
Должен пропустить 3 и 4 строку.

`(?<=>)([\d]+|[а-яёa-z]+)(?=<\/)|([\d]+|[а-яёa-z]+)`

`<p><sub>545454541</sub> <em>паапвапвапвап</em><em>weweeeeeeeee</em></p>
545454542 паапвапвапвап sassssssssaaa
<p><sub>545454543</sub></p>
5454545416`